# Should the asker edit an answer to a more complete, detailed version?

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

What should you do when the user asking the question [edits the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766823/saving-an-updated-core-data-instance/20767008#20767008) to a more complete or detailed solution?

The [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20767008/revisions) of the accepted answer was sort of pseudocode where specific details were missing.

Is it correct to keep that edit or is it better to do a rollback and ask the OP to put an edit in the question? Or should a new answer entirely be posted?

Comment: And why -1 without a comment?

Comment: It seems that the title doesn't jive with the body of the material.  Hang on, let's see what a little editing magic can do...

Comment: Can you give us a link to the question you are talking about?

Comment: As for the downvote: see the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. They often signal disagreement with stated sentiment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  [This is the one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20767008/1079354).

Comment: @Makoto, thank you very much. I agree with you.

Comment: Note that it was the [author of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3657733) that **accepted** the suggested edit by the OP! The answerer, at least, agreed with the edit.

Comment: I was just checking that.  Even though they accepted it, it still shouldn't be done like that.  I've left a note for the OP to post their own answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the info. I agree with you but in this case before editing I would ask the permission to who has answered the question. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: That is what a suggested edit **does**, it asks permission to change the post. And the answer author gave that permission by accepting the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it improved the answer, and the [original author agreed with the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3657733), there is **no reason** to roll back the edit.

Both the question and the answer should be helpful for *future visitors*. If the OP and answerer collaborated to improve the answer, I see no reason to prevent this kind of behaviour. In the end, we want good questions and helpful answers, answers that work for more than just the OP.

The code the OP added could be merged into a single cohesive answer, removing the sentence where the OP talks about how the code altered to make a working solution.

Sure, the author could have posted a new answer with the working code, but clearly the OP felt the answer helped and put him on the right path. The OP and answerer chose to collaborate rather than to compete for votes. *I say that that is great*.

Note that it should not matter whom made the edit, wether it was the OP or someone else.. Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited and we should allow for edits that improve a post. The suggested edit system reviews each edit on its merits, the author of the answer can always roll back if they don't agree with the edit. You need to pay attention to such cases, where the author of the post accepts the edit and is fine with it.

*tldr*: you should carefully review how the edit was made before jumping to conclusions. If an edit improves the answer, there never is a problem. If there is a case of OP adding a 'complete' solution where none is needed, do try to engage the OP in the comments to educate, don't just barge in. Give the author a chance to comment and correct too.

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree.  Both answers could stand separately on their own merits.

Comment: @Makoto: But the OP doesn't **have** to create a new answer. The OP felt that the answer helped him and he collaborated to improve the answer. Why is that wrong?

Comment: Martin, I agree with you. I missed the approval by the author of the answer. So, in this case is ok. But, in general, what if the edit was not the direct collaboration between OP and answerer?

Comment: We now have a special case when it comes to editing answers with code in them - if the answerer agrees to it.  I'm going to simply disagree; I'm not saying it's wrong or right, but my preference lies in a separate answer for both.

Comment: @flexaddicted: the normal suggested edit review process will kick in, and the author can still reject the edit too. If the edit was made by a 2k+ user, bypassing the reviews, the author can still roll back the edit *themselves*. Judge the edit itself on its merits, **not by whom made it**.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Forgot my previous comment. ;)

Comment: @Makoto: I know what type of edit you have in mind; I've rejected or rolled back plenty of edits with the 'final solution' from an OP not yet versed in how Stack Overflow works. Most of those edits don't add anything. But if the answer here started as pseudocode and all the OP did was add the version with the real code, otherwise functionally the same, I fail to see how a new answer would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Heck no.

If the OP figures out a better solution to their problem, let them write their own answer, **and** accept it.  This is a perfectly legitimate thing to do.  We even offer the option for users to [answer their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/175248) instantly as they're posted, Q&A style, if they already have a solution.

Editing others' answers doesn't help because:

- You're putting words in someone else's mouth
- The answer may still help others in the future
- You run the risk of invalidating an answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case the OP has edited the user's answer to add additional details. Where the details were specific for his answer.

Comment: That's not cool - no one should edit answers for that reason.  Could you show me the question?

Comment: Now I rolled back to maintain the original answer. So, for now it's ok. So, the correct behavior is to prevent such types of edit and ask the OP to edit the question or just create his own answer. Is it the right way?

Comment: That's correct.  Encourage them to answer their own question (they even get badges for it, if the stars are right), rather than change the answer of someone else.